# sites using java 3d ? ( need to develop 3d for the web )

Tags: java-3d

do you know good example of sites that using java 3d for there content ? 
i need to fine some kind of 3d solution , and now only java 3d solution is the best 
as i see it . but i didn't found any good site examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example visualisation applets using Java 3D](http://www.navgen.com/).

Comment: What about Java Applets using Java3D? Isn't it possible? (Genuine question, I really don't know)

Comment: i meant more commercial sites

Answer (score 1):

I saw many (non commercial, mostly artistic) 3D applets made with [Processing](http://processing.org/). It doesn't use Java3D (AFAIK), either self-made 3D or OpenGL (using JOGL IIRC).

There are also a number of 3D games, using one or the other 3D game engine like JMonkeyEngine.

I am not too sure of what you are looking for. If that's a kind of walk-though application, a game solution can be fitting. There are also 3D engines (in JavaScript, AFAIK) developed by Mozilla and, separately, by Google.

Note: like for pure Flash sites, there is a problem making a site all in Java: search engines like Google won't index its content...

Comment: its presentation application , 3d presentation  that shows 3d models

Answer (score 0):

[WoWHead](http://www.wowhead.com/), a World of Warcraft information database, has a "View in 3D" button for many things.  Clicking it brings up a small window that renders it with either a Flash or Java 3D applet. [(Example: Chillmaw)](http://www.wowhead.com/?npc=33687#modelviewer)